# Emacs auto-complete not working on a mac: "auto-complete error: (void-function valid-file)"

Tags: macos, emacs, autocomplete

I downloaded the official 1.3.1 .zip from the official site, and unzipped it. I'm on OS X Mountain Lion.

Fired up Emacs 24.3 and hit <kbd>M-x</kbd> to load `/etc/install.el` from the auto-complete source files.

No errors upon installation, but when I create a file called `test.py` I get this error:

```
auto-complete error: (void-function valid-file)
```

My `.emacs` file has nothing in it but this (which is what auto-complete told me to add):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)
```

That's right, I nuked my entire Emacs installation to isolate the problem, but this did not accomplish anything. Still failing with the same exact error.

For completeness, here are the contents of my `.emacs.d` folder:

```
ac-dict
auto-complete-config.el
auto-complete-config.elc
auto-complete.el
auto-complete.elc
auto-save-list
fuzzy.el
fuzzy.elc
popup.el
popup.elc
```

I did install auto-complete on a Linux computer (Ubuntu 12.10) with absolutely no problems on the first try following the directions, so I don't know what is going on.  Any ideas?

Comment: Two things: it is probably better to install packages using a package manager (this would at least try to take care of dependencies / the manager usually takes care to ensure the package is reasonably functional). Second, you can do `M-: (setq debug-on-error t)` and then you will get a stack trace of the code that caused this error, when it happens. This will give more information about what is going on in your setup. (I have autocomplete mode, but I don't have this function either).

Comment: Change your third line to `(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d//ac-dict")` (You need the `/` in front of ac-dict twice.

Comment: You may also have to call `expand-file-name` to resolve the tilde in your path to the intended _your home directory_.  Something like this:
`(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict"))`